# Passing an int variable between activities

Tags: android

I can't pass int variable between two activities, it always passes 0... here is my code, please help....

Sender class:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Senderclass.this, Receiverclass.class);

int  b = 2;
int  bb = 2;
myIntent.putExtra("aaa", b);
myIntent.putExtra("bbb", bb);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Reciver Class:

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
```

Oncreate....

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.on_a_same_device3);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if(bundle != null) { 
        aaa = getIntent().getIntExtra("aaa", 9); 
        bbb = getIntent().getIntExtra("bbb", 9);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code that I can see, show a more complete code sample please.

Comment: @vjdhama " it always passes 0"

Comment: where exactly is that zero. more code please

Comment: Use logs or breakpoints to see where the value is 0. Everything here looks correct.

Comment: i have a matrix of imageViews in the reciver class:
imgMat[aaa][bbb].setImageResource(R.drawable.pogodakmini);
and it changes imgMat[0][0] position, ok i'll try with breakpoints

Comment: And where is that code? Before or after the `Intent` code above?

Comment: about aaa = getIntent().getIntExtra("aaa", 9); How are aaa and bbb defined?

Comment: just int aaa; int bbb; before OnCreate...

Comment: On receiver class try overriding Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent), and in onNewIntent(Intent intent) { setIntent(intent); }

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.on_a_same_device3);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null) { 
        aaa = bundle.getInt("aaa");//I am not using default value.
        bbb = bundle.getInt("bbb", 9);//Using default value.
    }
}
```

Comment: The method getIntExtra(String) is undefined for the type Bundle